# Symfony3 Unable to find template prod

Tags: symfony

my website work in localhost, I have configure my site for prod and put the files on server, and when i go the site : http://tolkienbestiaire.esy.es/web/tolkien

**I have an error :**

```
Unable to find template "TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:index.html.twig" (looked into: /home/u493202215/public_html/app/Resources/views, /home/u493202215/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).
```

I don't understand why is shearch in "`app/Resources/views`" because the true way is `../public_html/src/Tolkien/BestiaireBundle/Resources/views`.

When I go to *`http://tolkienbestiaire.esy.es/web/login`* , **error was** :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(C:\wamp64\www\tolkien-bestiaire\app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

But *`C:\wamp64\www\tolkien-bestiaire\...`* is my local directory, the server directory is in public_html.

I work on windows, is a unix server.

Answer (score 0):

Right, then if it works, your routing is fine...

You can edit and delete the code files you copied from `/web`
This is not the file I was refering when I said your virtual host config

I was refering to the apache2 config file for your site
(exemple here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

Yours seems incomplete

If you want to see the result of your work without having to clear the cache, then you must pass by the app_dev.php file (http://tolkienbestiaire.esy.es/app_dev.php)

Though, that link will only work after the correction of your virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer.

virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName virtual-host-tolkien-bestiaire
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/tolkien-bestiaire
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/tolkien-bestiaire/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had hopped that you would take a look at the link I gave you of the Symfonny doc and find what you did wrong...

Your vhost point to `c:/wamp64/www/tolkien-bestiaire/` and not `c:/wamp64/www/tolkien-bestiaire/web/`

Also, if `c:/wamp64/www/tolkien-bestiaire` is the directory of your symfony project, there is no need of the first vhost in the same file.
It's first recommanded to have only one vhost per file.

The second exemple of the Symfony doc (http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) is a good vhost file exemple for Symfony.

I would suggest to run your terminal and to enamble the rewrite module `a2enmod rewrite`

Doing so should make it possible to go to your website with this link http://tolkienbestiaire.esy.es instead of the previous links you gave.

Hope it helped you fix the vhost problem.

Answer (score -1):

I empty the cache and now we can go to http://tolkienbestiaire.esy.es/web/login, http://tolkienbestiaire.esy.es/web/register and http://tolkienbestiaire.esy.es/web/about, about is in another bundle (

src

|-Tolkien

|    |-BestiaireBundle(http://tolkienbestiaire.esy.es/web/tolkien, home page, etc...)

|    |-CoreBundle(http://tolkienbestiaire.esy.es/web/about, and the main layout
)

app/config/routing.yml :

```
tolkien_cms:
    resource: "@TolkienCmsBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

tolkien_bestiaire:
    resource: "@TolkienBestiaireBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /tolkien

tolkien_core:
    resource: "@TolkienCoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

src/Tolkien/BestiaireBundle/BestiaireController.php :

```
<?php
namespace Tolkien\BestiaireBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Tests\A;
use Tolkien\BestiaireBundle\Entity\Bestiaire;
use Tolkien\BestiaireBundle\Event\MessagePostEvent;
use Tolkien\BestiaireBundle\Event\TolkienEvents;
use Tolkien\BestiaireBundle\Form\BestiaireEditType;
use Tolkien\BestiaireBundle\Form\BestiaireType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class BestiaireController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($page)
    {
        $nbPerPage = 5;

        $listBestiaires = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire')
            ->findAll();

        $nbPages = ceil(count($listBestiaires) / $nbPerPage);


        return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:index.html.twig', array(
            'listBestiaires' => $listBestiaires,
            'nbPages'     => $nbPages,
            'page'        => $page,
        ));

    }

    public function bestiaireAction()
    {
        $listBestiaires = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire')
            ->findAll();


        return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:bestiaire.html.twig', array(
            'listBestiaires' => $listBestiaires
        ));

    }

    public function viewAction(Bestiaire $bestiaire)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $listApplications = $em
            ->getRepository('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Application')
            ->findBy(array('bestiaire' => $bestiaire));



        return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:view.html.twig', array(
            'bestiaire'        => $bestiaire,
            'listApplications' => $listApplications,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_AUTEUR') or has_role('ROLE_USER') or has_role('ROLE_ADMIN') ")
     */
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $bestiaire = new Bestiaire();
        $form   = $this->get('form.factory')->create(BestiaireType::class, $bestiaire);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {


            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($bestiaire);
            $em->flush();

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Annonce bien enregistrée.');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('tolkien_bestiaire_view', array('id' => $bestiaire->getId()));
        }
        return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }



    /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_AUTEUR') or has_role('ROLE_USER') or has_role('ROLE_ADMIN') ")
     */
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $bestiaire = $em->getRepository('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire')->find($id);

        if (null === $bestiaire) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("L'annonce d'id ".$id." n'existe pas.");
        }

        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(BestiaireEditType::class, $bestiaire);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Annonce bien modifiée.');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('tolkien_bestiaire_view', array('id' => $bestiaire->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:edit.html.twig', array(
            'bestiaire' => $bestiaire,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Bestiaire $bestiaire)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create();

        if($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid())
        {
            $em->remove($bestiaire);
            $em->flush();

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('info', "L'annonce a bien été suprimée.");

            return $this->redirectToRoute('tolkien_bestiaire_home');
        }

        return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:delete.html.twig', array(
            'bestiaire' => $bestiaire,
            'form'   => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    public function menuAction($limit)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $listBestiaires = $em->getRepository('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire')->findBy(
            array(),
            array('date' => 'desc'),
            $limit,
            0
        );

        return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:menu.html.twig', array(
            'listBestiaires' => $listBestiaires
        ));
    }

    public function translationAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:translation.html.twig', array(
            'name' => $name
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @ParamConverter("json")
     */
    public function ParamConverterAction($json)
    {
        return new Response(print_r($json, true));
    }

    public function searchAction($name, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $this->getRequest()->get('query');

        if (!$query)
        {
            if(!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tolkien_bestiaire'));
            } else {
                return new Response('No results.');
            }
        }

        $bestiaire = $em->getRepository('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire')->find($name);

        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            if('*' == $query || !$bestiaire || $query == '') {
                return new Response('No results.');
            }
            return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:index.html.twig', array('bestiaire' => $bestiaire));
        }

        return $this->render('TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:search.html.twig', array(
            'bestiaire' => $bestiaire
        ));

    }

    public function testSearch()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/bestiaire/search');
        $this->assertEquals('Tolkien\BestiaireBundle\Controller\BestiaireController::searchAction', $client->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller'));

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/bestiaire/search?query=sens*', array(), array(), array(
            'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
        ));
        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('tr')->count()== 2);
    }

    public function updateDataAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->get('input');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery(''
            . 'SELECT c.id, c.name '
            . 'FROM TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire c '
            . 'WHERE c.name LIKE :data '
            . 'ORDER BY c.name ASC'
        )
            ->setParameter('data', '%' . $data . '%');
        $results = $query->getResult();

        $bestiaireList = '<ul id="matchList">';
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $matchStringBold = preg_replace('/('.$data.')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $result['name']); // Replace text field input by bold one
            $bestiaireList .= '<li id="'.$result['name'].'">'.$matchStringBold.'</li>'; // Create the matching list - we put maching name in the ID too
        }
        $bestiaireList .= '</ul>';

        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData(array('countryList' => $bestiaireList));
        return $response;
    }

}
```

src/Tolkien/BestiaireBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml :

```
tolkien_bestiaire_home:
    path:      /{page}
    defaults:
        _controller: TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:index
        page:        1
    requirements:
        page: \d*

tolkien_bestiaire_bestiaire:
    path: /bestiaire
    defaults:
        _controller: TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:bestiaire

tolkien_bestiaire_view:
    path:      /bestiaire/{id}
    defaults:
        _controller: TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:view
    requirements:
        id: \d+

tolkien_bestiaire_add:
    path:      /add
    defaults:
        _controller: TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:add

tolkien_bestiaire_edit:
    path:      /edit/{id}
    defaults:
        _controller: TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:edit
    requirements:
        id: \d+

tolkien_bestiaire_delete:
    path:      /delete/{id}
    defaults:
        _controller: TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:delete
    requirements:
        id: \d+

tolkien_bestiaire_paramconverter:
    path: /test/{json}
    defaults:
        _controller: "TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:ParamConverter"


tolkien_bestiaire_search:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: "TolkienBestiaireBundle:Bestiaire:search"


tuto_autocomplete:
    path:     /autocomplete
    defaults: { _controller: Sim100TutoBundle:Autocomplete:index }

ajax_autocomplete_countries:
  path:  /ajax/autocomplete/update/data
  defaults: { _controller: Sim100TutoBundle:AjaxAutocomplete:updateData }
```

virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName virtual-host-tolkien-bestiaire
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/tolkien-bestiaire
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/tolkien-bestiaire/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```